# How do I create a element as a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now i create a jQuery object by using

```
var content = $("Some string" + <a target="_blank" href="http://www.mypage.com"> + </a>);
```

But this seems not working.

How to fixed it?

Comment: What's the purpose of "Some String"? That's not an element.

Comment: this is just a string

Comment: var el  = $("<" + tagName + "/>", {"class": className});

Comment: It should be `$('<a target="_blank" href="http://example.com">' + 'Some string' + '</a>')`. A useful rule of thumb: wrap HTML attributes in double quotation marks, and JavaScript strings in single quotes, this improves readability big time. )

Comment: Well your code is not valid...That would be your first issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery constructor will only create you an element. It won't display it on the document until you append it. Also, the elements must be parsed as a string. Example:

```js
var content = $('<span>Some string</span><a target="_blank" href="http://www.mypage.com">Link</a>');
content.appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In your code, the HTML wasn't a string, so it most likely showed a SyntaxError or a TypeError.

Comment: You could write the `content` variable a little better anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting a string representation of `content` for wrapping in [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

```js
var content = "Some string" + "<a target=_blank href=http://www.mypage.com> + </a>";

$("body").append(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```